# mongoDB array inside document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When i update this data, the `deslon` and `deslat` part is not inserted in the document.

```
var locationData = { update_time: new Date() , 
                  location: [ 
                  {curlon: req.payload.loclon , curlat: req.payload.loclat},
                  {deslon: req.payload.deslon , deslat: req.payload.deslat}
                                   ]};
```

the update

```
userLocationModel.update({uid: req.params.accesskey}, locationData, { upsert: true }, function (err, numberAffected, raw) {
//DO SOMETHING
                });
```

I cannot understand why this is happining.

**Here is the mongo document that gets inserted. The `deslon` and `deslat` are missing even if a new document is created.**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("52f876d7dbe6f9ea80344fd4"),
  location: [
    {
      curlon: 160,
      curlat: 160,
      _id: ObjectId("52f8788578aa340000e51673")
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId("52f8788578aa340000e51672")
    }
  ],
  uid: "testuser6",
  update_time: ISODate("2014-02-10T06:58:13.790Z")
}
```

**Also : Should I be using a structure like this if the document is updated frequently.**

This is the mongoose model:

```
var userLocationSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    uid: String,                //same as the user access key
    update_time: Date,          //time stamp to validate, insert when updating. created by server.  

    location:[                
        {
            curlon: Number,         //current location in latitude and longitude <INDEX>
            curlat: Number
        },
        {
            deslon: Number,         //destination in latitude and longitude <INDEX>
            deslat: Number
        }
        ]
});
```

I wish to update both of the elemets. I don't wan't to insert a new one. But even when I update a non existent document(ie- which results in the creation of a new one), the deslon and deslat are missing.

Comment: To help anyone (mostly for me I guess) in answering you might do well to include your understanding of why those `_id` fields are there on the sub-documents in your location field.

Comment: The _id fields are added by the MongoDB Driver.

Comment: Erm. Not quite. I'm fairly sure you don't want them there really. Your mongoose schema may not actually be what you want. Which I or someone else may get to in time to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a real problem with this structure but, oh well.

Your Schema is wrong for doing this. Hence also the superfluous `_id` entries. To do what you want you need something like this:

```
var currentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  curlon: Number,
  curlat: Number
});

var destSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  destlon: Number,
  destlat: Number
});

var userLocationSchema = mongoose.Schema({

  uid: String,
  update_time: Date,

  location: [ ]

});
```

This is how mongoose expects you to do embedded documents. That will allow the update in your form you are using to work.

Also your logic on `upsert` is wrong as you have not included the **new** uid that is not found in the updated document part. You should take a look at [**$setOnInsert**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) in the MongoDB documentation, or just live with updating it every time.

Actually, I'm just pointing you to how to separate the schema. As your usage in code stands `location` will accept *anything* by the above definition. See the mongoose docs on [Embedded Documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.8.x/docs/embedded-documents.html) for a more detailed usage.

This will work with your update statement as stands. However I would strongly urge you to re-think this schema structure, especially if you intend to do Geo-spatial work with the data. That's out of the scope of this question. Happy googling.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell mongo **how** to update your data. So add a simple `$set` to your update data:

```
var locationData = {
    $set: {
        update_time: new Date(), 
        location: [ 
            {curlon: req.payload.loclon , curlat: req.payload.loclat},
            {deslon: req.payload.deslon , deslat: req.payload.deslat}
        ]
    };
```

**EDIT:**

If you do not want to exchange the `location` property as a whole, but insert a new item into the array, use:

```
var locationData = {
    $set: {
        update_time: new Date() 
    },
    $push: {
        location: [ 
            {deslon: req.payload.deslon , deslat: req.payload.deslat}
        ]
    };
```

What you should consider is, if it is a good idea to put the current location and the destinations in one array, just because they have the same properties (lon/lat). If for example, there is always **one** current location and zero to many destinations, you could put the current location into a separate property.

To modify a specific location within an array, you can address it via.

```
var index = 2, // this is an example 
    arrayElement = 'location.' + n,
    locationData = { $set: {} };

locationData.$set[arrayElement] = {deslon: req.payload.deslon , deslat: req.payload.deslat};

userLocationModel.update({uid: req.params.accesskey}, locationData );
```

Comment: Note that the query and update parts do not say which **index** of the **Array** to update, push etc. Leading to the next question of "why does this always update the first item?"

Comment: Mongo does not know which element to update, if you do not tell. Which one do you want to?

Comment: Or do you just want to insert a new item into your array? Then see my EDIT.

Comment: I wish to update both of the elemets. I don't wan't to insert a new one. But even when I update a non existent document(ie- which results in the creation of a new one), the deslon and deslat are missing.

Comment: @heinob He is working with mongoose and the Schema was wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

could it be that the intial collection was built with an other version of the schema? i.e. one that had only curlon and curlat? you may have to update the documents then to reflect the amended schema with the deslon and deslat properties.